# ActiveMq, Camel, Transaction Timeout

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am having issues actually getting a timeout exception to occur with Camel, and ActiveMQ. I have the following Route setup:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("activemq:queue:test.queue")
        .transacted()
        .beanRef("testMessageHandler", "handle");
}
```

I have the following CamelContext Setup:

```
CamelGuiceRegistry rego = new CamelGuiceRegistry(injector);

ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(connectionString);
connectionFactory.setUserName("user");
connectionFactory.setPassword("password");

PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager = injector.getInstance(Key.get(PlatformTransactionManager.class, Names.named("transactionManager")));

JmsComponent jmsCom = JmsComponent.jmsComponentTransacted(connectionFactory, transactionManager);
jmsCom.setTransactionTimeout(1);

GuiceCamelContext context = new GuiceCamelContext(injector);
context.setRegistry(rego);
context.addComponent("activemq", jmsCom);
```

And lastly the `QueueHandlerImpl` code:

```
public void handle(String body, Exchange exchange) throws JMSException {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (Exception ex ){
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Note how the thread that is doing work lasts significantly longer than the 1 second set on the `jmsComponent`.

When running the example, I receive the message, "process" for 10 seconds, then return. However, I have set the transaction timeout to 1, and thus would expect the "process" to timeout due to the transaction timeout set. However there is no exception thrown, and the bean reference specified continues to work incorrectly.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: This http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/configure-transaction-timeout-in-camel-route-td5718339.html is a similar question and suggests that setting a timeout on a JMS transaction isn't supported.

Comment: Can you clearly mention what is the problem that you're facing or is there something that you're trying to achieve?